# Problems with "mysqli_insert_id"

Tags: mysql

need a little help with adding product to database. error reported on "mysqli_insert_id" line Here is my code:

```
// Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,"INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$subcategory',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysqli_insert_id($sql);
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
```

Here is the Error it produces:

```
Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /.....line 45
```

"Funny thing is that it still inserts the text into database & it shows up on my site but I still get the Error if I add another product.

my table **does** have Auto_Increment set on id

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ralph

Comment: The error means the query failed, it didn't produce a valid result. You need to use mysql error handling so you can catch the Mysql query errors

Comment: @helion3, I think the INSERT succeeded, but mysqli_query() still returned a boolean value.

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) for mysqli_insert_id():

```
mixed mysqli_insert_id ( mysqli $link )
```

The argument to the function should be your `$myConnection` resource, not the `$sql` result from your INSERT statement.

When you run an INSERT statement, mysqli_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
So you're passing the boolean value TRUE instead of a connection resource.

Comment: Yah that was it. I tried everything in the book but missed that one. Thanks so much.